# Remove mark from ring in org mode

Tags: org-mode

Once I have pushed a mark into the ring with `C-c %`, `org-mark-ring-push` and have cycled through the ring with `C-c &`, `org-mark-ring-goto`, how can I remove a mark that I don't need anymore? I tried `C-u C-u` `set-mark-command-repeat-pop` but nothing happens.

Comment: I don't see a command to remove something from `org-mark-ring` in Orgmode.

Answer (score 1):

`org-mark-ring-goto` is buggy in [the current org-mode master as of 2017-12-22](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/org.el?id=6e95e088e8a3b5bd41fd6efd8c251b12f6ced61b#n10804).
All markers in the mark ring are set to `nil` at the beginning of an emacs session and `org-mark-ring-goto` does not treat this case correctly.

If `org-mark-ring-goto` is corrected deleting the current mark is a piece of cake. One can just set the mark at `org-mark-ring-last-goto` to `nil`.

Here is a corrected version of `org-mark-ring-goto` with a corresponding possible `org-mark-ring-delete`:

```el
(require 'subr-x)

(defun org-mark-ring-marker-p (ring-pos)
  "Return marker at RING-POS if it has a non-nil buffer
and nil otherwise."
  (when (consp ring-pos)
    (let* ((marker (car ring-pos))
       buffer)
      (when (and (markerp marker)
         (buffer-live-p (setq buffer (marker-buffer marker))))
    marker))))

(defun org-mark-ring-next (&optional ring-pos n)
  "Find next `org-mark-ring' position with valid marker starting at
`org-mark-ring-last-goto' if non-nil or `org-mark-ring' otherwise.
With non-nil RING-POS start there.
Return nil if all markers have no buffer."
  (unless n (setq n 1))
  (let (marker
        (pos (setq ring-pos (or ring-pos org-mark-ring-last-goto org-mark-ring))))
    (while (and
            (or (null (setq marker (org-mark-ring-marker-p pos)))
                (prog1 (> n 0) (cl-decf n)))
            (null (eq ring-pos
                      (setq pos (cdr pos))))))
    (and marker pos)))

(defun org-mark-ring-goto-ad (&optional n)
  "Jump to N -th previous position in `org-mark-ring'."
  (let ((p (if (eq last-command this-command)
               (org-mark-ring-next nil n)
             (org-mark-ring-next org-mark-ring 0))))
    (if p
        (let ((m (car p)))
          (setq org-mark-ring-last-goto p)
          (pop-to-buffer-same-window (marker-buffer m))
          (goto-char m)
          (when (or (org-invisible-p) (org-invisible-p2)) (org-show-context 'mark-goto)))
      (message "There are not as many as %d marks in `org-mark-ring'." n))))

(advice-add #'org-mark-ring-goto :override #'org-mark-ring-goto-ad)

(defun org-mark-ring-delete ()
  "Delete the mark pointed to by `org-mark-ring-last-goto' in `org-mark-ring'.
That is mark holding the position reached by the last `org-mark-ring-goto'."
  (interactive)
  (when (org-mark-ring-marker-p org-mark-ring-last-goto)
    (set-marker (car org-mark-ring-last-goto) nil)))
```